# How do I point a gameobject towards another one, while it's rotating around a moving player?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions, raycasting

Im making a space exploration game and I'm trying to have an arrow rotating around the player, pointing towards the sun in the center of the level. This is to make the game more readable.
The "arrow" is for now just a cylinder with a sphere on it - with the sphere representing the arrow point. The rotation around the player is working, but I can't get it to point towards the sun, consistently. As seen in the image here, the arrow is pointing almost opposite of where I want it to.

[image: Left to right : Sun, Arrow, Player]

The code I'm using is as follows

```
    playerPos = transform.position;
    sunPos = sun.transform.position;

    // Cast ray from player to sun
    Ray ray = new Ray(playerPos, sunPos - playerPos);
    RaycastHit hitInfo;

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo, 400, mask))
        Debug.DrawLine(ray.origin, sunPos, Color.green);
    Debug.Log("Distance" + hitInfo.distance);
    
    // Rotate arrow around player.
    arrow.transform.position = playerPos + ray.direction.normalized*2;
    // Point arrow towards sun. This is not working
    arrow.transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(gameObject.transform.position, sunPos);
```

In addition to Quaternion.FromToRotation I have also tried using LookAt, which also gave me weird results. (I tried all the different up directions, i.e. LookAt(sun, Vector3.left) and (sun, Vector3.back), etc.
Hoping some clever minds can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Transform.LookAt rotates the object's Z axis towards the target. Can you show the world and local coordinates of the arrow?

Comment: Okay that would explain alot. The z axis isnt used in my game.. Gonna upload an image

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/z0NYDxg)

Comment: The coordinates of the arrow depends on the coordinates of the player. The arrow is always "in between" the player and the sun. Z axis is always 0

Comment: You can edit the cylinder and the sphere object to be along the arrow's +z axis.

Comment: By the way you don't need raycast to get the sun distance and direction.

```Vector3 delta = sunPos - playerPos;
Vector3 direction = delta.normalized;
float distance = delta.magnitude;```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Theory**

You can use

> Quaternion.FormToRotation

It create a quaternion (thing who handle the rotation of your gameobject) by giving a direction vector and the "0" vector. With these informations it'll know how to rotate your transform.

**Exemple**

I would do something like :

```
Vector3 direction = sunPos - playerPos;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(direction, Vector3.right);
```

Vector3.right = (1f,0f,0f) and you should use the standard direction of your arrow. For exemple if when arrow have no rotation it point up (0f,1f,0f), you should use Vector3.up insteed.

As I said on comment you don't need raycast for this. (Maybe you need it later on your code)

```
Vector3 delta = sunPos - playerPos;
Vector3 direction = delta.normalized;
float distance = delta.magnitude;
```